# Why does external server register uid instead of username of user-generated user?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, username, uid

I'm running a cluster in Ubuntu generated by AWS ParallelCluster. When I run the cluster as the default user "ubuntu" with uid:gid 1000:1000, the cluster calls to a license manager on a separate server and registers the user by assigning a seat respectively with the format ubuntu@hostname.

To allow multiple users, I wanted to have each user with their own logins and call the cluster individually. As such, I have generated a second user with `adduser newuser` and then `sudo usermod -aG sudo newuser`, as the user requires sudo privileges to call the cluster program.
When I check the `/etc/passwd` I can see this user has been added with uid:gid 1001:1001, which I expect, and is part of the sudo group. However, now when I run the cluster process, my license manager registers the user as 1001:hostname instead of newuser:hostname.  It seems the user "newuser" makes the request with the uid whereas the user "ubuntu" makes the request with the username.

Is there a setting I haven't amended that maps the username to external services instead of the uid?